# C++/CLI DLL > Upcasting

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm writing a small wrapper using C++/CLI to wrap a C++ dll so i can use it in a C#.net environment. But I need to find a way around a 'small' casting problem. This is a small 'sketch' of how the classes look like:

[WRAPPER DLL CODE]

//ManagedBaseClass

```
public ref class ManagedBaseClass
{
public:
    ManagedBaseClass(BaseClass* nativePtr):
        m_NativePtr(nativePtr)
        {}

internal:
    BaseClass* m_NativePtr;
};
```

//ManagedSomeClass

```
public ref class ManagedSomeClass: ManagedBaseClass
{
public:
    ManagedSomeClass(SomeClass* nativePtr):
        ManagedBaseClass((BaseClass*)nativePtr), 
        m_NativePtr(nativePtr)
        {}

    //Convert-From (BaseClass* can be casted up to SomeClass*)
    static explicit operator ManagedSomeClass^ (ManagedBaseClass^ obj)
    {
        return gcnew ManagedSomeClass((SomeClass*)obj->m_NativePtr);
    }

internal:
    SomeClass* m_NativePtr;
};
```

So this is the setup. Now I need to handle the following scenario (in C#):

[C#, using the Wrapper Dll]

```
var someClass = (ManagedSomeClass)baseClassObj; //Taking into account
that i can do the conversion on the C++ side using an explicit cast.
```

The cast doesn't work at the moment.
Am i doing something wrong or is there another way? (And I want to keep the current class-setup, just trying to get the casting on the C# side to work)

Comment: Please clarify how "the cast doesn't work". Compiler error? Runtime exception? No exception, but the `someClass` object isn't behaving properly?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. At the moment i'm getting an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Show us how `baseClassObj` is declared.  Are you just missing a hat `^` in the cast?

Comment: The cast of `baseClassObj` is in C#, no need for hats.

Comment: This cannot work, you are giving the C# compiler **two** ways to convert the object.  It likes the explicit reference conversion better.  Either break the inheritance, make it an implicit operator or provide a plain Convert method.

Comment: Breaking the inheritance does the job. I wonder if there isn't a way to force it to use the op_explicit conversion.

Comment: Removing `managed-c++` tag. The syntax for it is vastly different and this question is obviously C++/CLI.